# Querying nested latitude and longitude fields in Opendatasoft API

Tags: coordinates, query

I'm working with the Opendatasoft API, specifically accessing the "geonames-all-cities-with-a-population-1000@public" dataset. I need to perform queries based on the latitude and longitude, which are nested inside the 'coordinates' field of the returned JSON objects. However, I've encountered difficulties when attempting to filter cities by their latitude or longitude using ODSQL syntax.
The JSON structure for each city includes nested 'coordinates' like so:

```
{
    "total_count":141153,
    "results":[
        {
            "geoname_id":"1275339",
            "name":"Mumbai",
            ...
            "population":12691836,
            "coordinates":{
                "lon":72.88261,
                "lat":19.07283
               }
},...
```

For example, adding **population > 1000000** in the URL works.

However, I've tried various query formats in the API URL, such as coordinates.lat, coordinates[lat], and other combinations, but none have been successful.

I've looked through the [Opendatasoft API documentation](https://help.opendatasoft.com/apis/ods-explore-v2/), but I've not been able to find specific examples or guidelines on how to properly query nested fields like latitude and longitude within 'coordinates'. I need to, for example, retrieve all cities with a latitude higher than 60.

Can you provide the correct ODSQL syntax for querying nested fields or point me toward the relevant part of the Opendatasoft documentation that I may have overlooked or let me know if this query is even possible?